# How can I reveal objects on my webpage one by one?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my code works the following:

1. "choosing a payment method"
2. "are you sure?"

The buttons:

- "yes, I'm sure (with link to the page of PayPal, for example)"
- "no, I want to choose another one"

now I have the following code:

```
document.getElementById("headerButton228").onclick = function(){
    let myfRadioBtn = document.getElementById("visaCard");
    let mysRadioBtn = document.getElementById("masterCard");
    let mytRadioBtn = document.getElementById("paypalCard");
    const textForFirstOption = "Are you sure you would like to use Visa Card?";
    const editedTextForFirstOption = `<strong>${textForFirstOption}</strong>`;
    const textForSecondOption = "Are you sure you would like to use Master Card?";
    const editedTextForSecondOption = `<strong>${textForSecondOption}</strong>`;
    const textForThirdOption = "Are you sure you would like to use PayPal?";
    const editedTextForThirdOption = `<strong>${textForThirdOption}</strong>`;
    const textIfNothing = "You need to choose one option!";
    const editedTextIfNothing = `<strong>${textIfNothing}</strong>`;
    

    if(myfRadioBtn.checked){
        document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = editedTextForFirstOption;
    }
    else if(mysRadioBtn.checked){
        document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = editedTextForSecondOption;
    }
    else if(mytRadioBtn.checked){
        document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = editedTextForThirdOption;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = editedTextIfNothing;
    }
        document.getElementById("paragraph2").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<button type="button" id="headerButton328">Choose</button><br>');
}
```

I've tried to google and to ask ChatGPT for help but still no result

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Also search the net for javascript wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your html looks something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="cardChose" value="Visa Card" id="visaCard">
<input type="radio" name="cardChose" value="Master Card" id="masterCard">
<input type="radio" name="cardChose" value="PayPal" id="paypalCard">
<button id="headerButton228">Click</button>
<p id="paragraph"></p>
<p id="paragraph2"></p>
```

If so, then your only mistake is that there are no quotes in

```
document.getElementById(paragraph2).insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<button type="button" id="headerButton328">Choose</button><br>');
```

However, using .insertAdjasentHTML is not the best practice. Your "choose" buttons will be created and stack one over another every time you chose the payment method.

Also, your JS code can be improved a lot, using values of buttons and query selectors.
Here is my quick solution to you problem:

```
document.getElementById("headerButton228").onclick = () => {
    const activeRadioButton = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked') //  Make sure you selector selects correct radio buttons
    
    document.querySelector('#paragraph').innerHTML = "Are you sure you would like to use " + activeRadioButton.value
    document.getElementById('paragraph2').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<button type="button" id="headerButton328">Choose</button><br>');
}
```

Query selectors can provide you a lot more flexibility choosing elements on the page